# How is NaN saved during run time?

Tags: c, floating-point

I had a small function where at one point I divided by 0 and created my first NaN. After looking on the internet I did find out the NaN - not a number and NaN != NaN.

My questions are:

1. During run time how is NaN saved or how does the controller know that a variable has the NaN value?(I am working with small micro controllers(c language), the mechanism is different in programs that are running on a pc(c# and other OOP languages))?
2. Inf is similar to NaN?

Comment: You might like to [read this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: Please ask a *single* question. While 2 and 3 are fairly similar and can reasonably be in the same question, question 1 is very, very different to the others. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: `NaN` occurs for floating point numbers, which have a specific pattern of bits which represents `NaN`. Like how in an unsigned integer, `1010` represents 10. They can also represent `Inf` in this way, so it's similar in that it's a "special value" with a "special bit pattern". The rules for arithmetic when working with these values are also defined in the IEEE 754.

Comment: I know nothing of c, but I do know c# - and in c#, `NaN` will never be equal to any value, not even if you compare the same variable (i.e var d = double.NaN; if(d==d) // will always return false`

Comment: and C#  and C are quite different from each other.

Comment: No different from the way, say, 0.0 or 1.0 are stored.  There is a dedicated bit pattern that represents NaN.  A bunch of them, actually, but C# only uses one.  Just check out the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Encoding) for relevant links if you want to dig in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In C, the types of values are determined statically by your source code. For named objects (“variables”), you explicitly declare the types. For constants, the syntax of them (e.g., `3` versus `3.`) determines the type. In typical C implementations that compile to machine code on common processors, the processors have different instructions for working with integers and floating-point. The compiler uses integer instructions for integers and floating-point instructions for floating-point values. The floating-point instructions are designed in hardware to work with encodings of floating-point values.
2. In IEEE-754 binary floating-point, floating-point data is encoded with a sign bit, an exponent field, and a significand field. If the exponent field is all ones and the significand field is not all zeros, the datum represents a NaN. In common modern processors, this is built into the hardware.
3. Infinity is not largely similar to a NaN. They might both be considered special in that they are not normal numbers and are processed somewhat differently from normal numbers. However, in IEEE-754 arithmetic, infinity is a number and participates in arithmetic. NaN is not a number.

Comment: For the response 2, if there is float a = NaN, if I write a == 5.0, there is a specific code that checks 1st if "the exponent field is all ones and the significand field is not all zeros, the datum represents a NaN" and depending on this 2nd if is NaN gives false otherwise checks if a == 5.0 and gives true/ false?

Comment: @dorin.petre: Most commonly, this is built into the hardware. The processor has a floating-point compare instruction. When that instruction is executed, the floating-point arithmetic unit inside the processor examines the bits of the two values. If it sees one of them has an exponent field of all ones and a non-zero significand, it knows it is a NaN and produces false for the comparison. Since this is built into hardware, there is no software for it. The program simply executes a floating-point compare instruction and gets the proper result.

Comment: @dorin.petre: If you have a C compiler for a processor that does not have floating-point support, then the compiler must provide software that implements floating-point. In that case, the software must examine the bits itself in order to determine whether a number is a NaN.